# How to format string to two decimal points?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

in SSRS report I have field which shows numbers but it is string value, so results are like: "20.00000", "25.00000" etc..

This field is in sales invoice report "printCode" field.

How can I format it to have values like 20.00, 25.00 etc..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the text box, choose expression

Convert the string to a number using val:

```
=val(Fields!printCode.Value)
```

Right click on the text box and select text box properties.

Choose Number

Enter the number of decimal places

[image: Number format]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
=Format(Fields!printCode.Value,"F2")
```

Comment: I added it to Format propery as expression, report is opened with same Value like 20.00000. Of course I deployed report after change

Comment: @AYETY:- Strange. Anyways can you try this: `=Format(Fields!printCode.Value, "#,##0.##")
`

Comment: unfortunately same with "#,##0.##" too.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.   Put it in the Format property of the text box:

```
#,0.00;(#,0.00)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Is those examples for string value as printCode field is stringEdit?

Comment: What does that mean?    What is stringEdit?

Comment: sorry, stringEdit is type of field that gets string values in MS Dynamics Ax. It's equal to textbox and I wanted to say that printCode field is not numeric but string

Comment: Ok, well I don't know what Dynamics Ax is, but it is apparently interfering with the format of textboxes, since the format string I gave works for me in a standard SSRS textbox.